java jpa get the details from parents, child and grandhild table
I have three tables
Example
Table1 -> Car
Table2 -> Brand
Table3 -> Parameters
Table 3 -> Model

Car has one to many relationship with brand and parameters
Brand has one to many relationship with model

@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "graph-a",
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("brand"),
                @NamedAttributeNode("parameters")
        }
)

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class CAR {
    @Id
    private long carId;
    
    private String name;
    
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "car")   
    private Set<Brand> brands;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "car")
    private Set<Params> params = new HashSet<>();

}


@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "graph-with-children",
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("models"),
        }
)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BRAND")
public class BRAND  {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BRANDID id;

    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "brands")
    private Set<MODEL> models;

     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
     private Car car;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "MODEL")
public class MODEL  {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ModelId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_ID", referencedColumnName = "BRAND_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID", referencedColumnName = "CAR_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private BRAND brands;
}

And my repository method is
@Override
    @EntityGraph(value = "graph-a")
    Optional<Car> findById(Long carId);

When i run this code i am able to get the car details , brand details but not the model details
When i do brand.getModels() it throws an exception
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' 
exception.


In my opinion, this issue occurs because Hibernate cannot perform lazy loading when the Model is not specified in the EntityGraph annotation of findById, or when the transaction scope of findById only applies to that query.
I think you could try the following solutions:

Using Entity Graphs

In your repository, use the updated graph:
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "graph-a-with-models",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("brand"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("parameters"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "brands", subgraph = "brand-subgraph")
    },
    subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
            name = "brand-subgraph",
            attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("models")
        )
    }
)

@Override
@EntityGraph(value = "graph-a-with-models")
Optional<Car> findById(Long carId);



Extend Transaction Scope

@Service
@Transactional
public class CarService {
    public Car getCarWithDetails(Long carId) {
        Car car = carRepository.findById(carId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CarNotFoundException("Car not found"));
        
        for (Brand brand : car.getBrands()) {
            brand.getModels();  // Lazy loading occurs inside the transaction
        }

        return car;
    }
}

I hope my predictions and presentation are correct

Thanks iohny i realised that i was using the subgraph value wrong.
